# Writing Unit Test of Interceptors

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, okhttp, spock

I am working on a project where I need to write an interceptor which basically modifies headers. Below is a similar code

```
class AuthRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "auth-value"); 
    
        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

I want to test if Authorization has been added to the request header by the interceptor. Here is the code for testing

```
class AuthRequestInterceptorTest extends Specification {
    AuthRequestInterceptor authRequestInterceptor = new AuthRequestInterceptor();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    void setup() {
        try {
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(authRequestInterceptor)
                .build();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new WebClientException(e)
        }
    }


    def "Get Authorization in to header"() {

        given:
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>()

        when:
        Request mockRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://1.1.1.1/heath-check")
            .headers(Headers.of(headers))
            .build()

       Response res = okHttpClient.newCall(mockRequest).execute()

        then:
        res.headers("Authorization")
    }
}
```

The test is failing so I debugged the Response returned by AuthRequestInterceptor and it is as below

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://1.1.1.1/}
```

I want to test if the Authorization key is added in request headers, But I an able to get Response only and not able to figure out how to get the request header

Comment: What have you tried so far? A unit test requires that you can test the interceptor in isolation, so having an anonymous class is bad, you'd need to make the interceptor a top-level class and then use Mocks to simulate the execution.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I have edited the question with granular details and what I have tried so far

Comment: Verifying the **response** header and checking for a header that you put into the **request** does not make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Helper class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74575745;

class WebClientException extends RuntimeException {
  public WebClientException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
  }
}
```

**Class under test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74575745;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import java.io.IOException;

class AuthRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    // Request customization: add request headers
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
      .header("Authorization", "auth-value");

    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

**Spock specification:**

In order to test your interceptor in isolation, just mock the interceptor chain parameter, making sure that it returns a request without headers. Then verify that the `proceed(Request)` method is called with a request parameter containing the header you expect.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74575745

import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Request
import spock.lang.Specification

class AuthRequestInterceptorTest extends Specification {
  def "request contains authorization header"() {
    given: "a mock interceptor chain returning a prepared request without headers"
    def chain = Mock(Interceptor.Chain) {
      request() >> new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://1.1.1.1/heath-check")
        .build()
    }

    when: "running the interceptor under test"
    new AuthRequestInterceptor().intercept(chain)

    then: "the expected authorization header is added to the request before proceeding"
    1 * chain.proceed({ Request request -> request.headers("Authorization") == ["auth-value"] })
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJytVE1r20AQvetXDLpEKvUaNw0BG4ekoZQcSiAN9FBKWa_G1tbSrrIfdmjIf89Iq7UVJ82ltcCSdmbefLw3arhY8xVCgcwK4-tfNbcODbOODHqDZlnpLbs7_XhyekJ_SSLrRhsHel061xyzK0XeAhunzaHpBu88WhePbaPFmlVcrdi3BoVcSsGd1CpJRMWthQvvyj5kAHpLr4D3DlVh4VkcPCRAZS8hNSEKhFaOS2WBE5Q28k_wK5EXaNIs7yIAVnKDagoph5oqArlPBqKkeDDovFFSrYBDY7DhBguISbaSsL3rUW3aQbZlhNg5fCXQbNABu2wNMTlEICrn7AwUbqFvmn3ysiLILO8dAZg3VZa205yOxxPWXWNK7MqRKFGs04Hroo3uYx-T7rYtuz6NV10zrsRnzXpF2cBR6tBEW8vrJGQ52wVmXZ95yOBChhYZ74kcR4N6bfggiZSiIKvTXR1xmgtcaoM0ZS0QC6oylDKBd2GerLdkD3FMu9DRWXxkPRdZejHMneYwn8OPtC1otOGVx_QnPLYTekxoQuMxjP7h99YmzP6yCq-c01Yoi7Md2m--4UxqdnX9-b4Foz7IeP7F8EV2JHTN7J0nPfqG9RjTcJ8es8kHNjk-yt9cJ6A0FdaonIXhcSvO82tadyMLpOfGLyopINa3181LZQeicqLV6C2h7gvvJR-JI2JWUvGKdiRwu9uEWVATMRJ9hbdO1z2R01Y7O957sofQcXWiT3yd73IyEvfhfvWyOVTNexgqJtZ2qL75Qa64f7Mk7Hj7BTmQcB_QufwfBQamv-PispJE6X7w8YN545WTNT5npOf2ZVh221LIFxWC4N5i_GZZ39CYwlEs_gnmggs-).

You probably want to learn about Spock [argument constraints](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints).